# Aldrin cycler mission to Mars in MATLAB

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, spacecraft, orbital-maneuver

I am planning to do a mission project on Aldrin Cycler (Earth to Mars) in MATLAB. Can you please suggest me where to start.

I tried reading few research paper related to this topic, any other advice?

Comment: you could look at posts that contain "[Aldrin Cycler](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=Aldrin+Cycler)} on this site, and then ask a more specific question. Stack Exchange is a great place to get answers to *specific questions* but "...any other advice?" is too open-ended.